# WPF: How To Use Command & Input Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf

Command & Input Bindings seem to be extremely complicated in WPF - binding specific commands to certain inputs don't always seem to work. How should I go about doing this?

--Self Answered--

I've updated with a personal answer with my own findings considering how long it's taken me to find information, understand, and actually implement these convoluted things.

Bindings in WPF seem to be an unfriendly concept, especially if you have no experience. Hopefully this makes people's lives easier.

Comment: When creating a self-answered question, we do require that you post an *actual question*. One that meets the usual quality standards of the site and can stand on its own without having been answered yet.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hi, thanks for the comment - while it feels somewhat weird updating the question like this, let me know how the change looks.

Comment: If you found this question on the site, do you think you could answer it? Don't put things like *--Self Answered--* in the post, that has no bearing on the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I recall correctly, there was no question - so I asked, didn't get a reply, so I wrote the answer up. How should I change this - do you just want the 'self answered' part deleted?

Comment: At the very least; your question, if asked today, would still get closed as too broad or unclear.

Answer (score 23):

First, add the application namespace at the top of xaml file that will use the binding: ex.

`xmlns:main="clr-namespace:MyApplication"`

Next, add a custom **static** class to contain the commands, **outside** the main window class: ex.

```
public static class Command
{
    public static RoutedCommand GSToggleCmd = new RoutedCommand();
    public static RoutedCommand ScreenZoomCmd = new RoutedCommand();
}
```

My main window class happened to be 'MainWindow'; I defined the Command class right below it.

Finally, add the command bindings in the xaml file

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="main:Command.GSToggleCmd" Executed="GameStateToggleExecuted" />
    <CommandBinding Command="main:Command.ScreenZoomCmd" Executed="ApplyScreenFitCmd" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

`Command=""` refers to the `RoutedCommand` that you'll be binding to. I've named my namespace reference `main`, hence the syntax `main:Command.nameofcommand`

`Executed=""` refers to the function called when the command is triggered.

Example of `Executed` function:

```
private void ApplyScreenFitCmd( object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args )
{
    string proportionStr = args.Parameter as string;
}
```

And that's it. A minimalistic, simple approach to using `CommandBindings` in `WPF`.

To add a command, just chuck in a new static `RoutedCommand` in the `Command` class and add the `CommandBinding` in the xaml file under `Window.CommandBindings`

**Note:**

Visual Studio's Xaml editor may complain at first that some command cannot be found. Building the project will resolve the issue.

**Further Information**:

You can also trigger `CommandBindings` through **InputBindings**. (key triggers)

Example (placed in the Xaml file that will use them):

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F5" Command="main:Command.GSToggleCmd" />
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Shift+Alt" Key="Q" Command="main:Command.ScreenZoomCmd" CommandParameter="1.0" />
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Alt" Key="W" Command="main:Command.ScreenZoomCmd" CommandParameter="0.75" />
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Alt" Key="E" Command="main:Command.ScreenZoomCmd" CommandParameter="0.5" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

So it's basically the `Key` press triggers `KeyBinding`, which in turn triggers the `CommandBinding` of the command specified, triggering the corresponding call function.

As with the above example, you can also define `CommandParameter` to send in a parameter to the function finally called. The nice thing about this is that, like the above, you can reuse the same `CommandBinding` by just chucking in different `CommandParameters`.

You can also trigger `CommandBindings` through **Buttons, MenuItems, etc.**

Example:

```
<MenuItem Header="100%" InputGestureText="Alt+Q" Command="main:Command.ScreenZoomCmd" CommandParameter="1.0"/>
```

This is the same syntax as with the `InputBindings`.

It took me a while before I settled down on a minimalistic, uniform way to use bindings in WPF. I hope this article prevents all the struggle that this concept seems to easily cause.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped. Just a quick addendum: if you happen to have a command that you want to handle in a different window than this one, you don't have to create the command handler here and forward the command manually. Just use CommandTarget={Binding ElementName=NameOfYouControl} together with the Command="..." specification.

Comment: nice job it was really useful and it helped me in understanding this concept

Comment: Very good. This really solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks this is really very well written, but just to ask how to chose between both the options?
Invoking CommandBindings alone
or
Invoking CommandBinding through InputBindings