# How do I check on the properties of WPF elements whilst in a different class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am following a bunch of different examples etc and trying to do my own thing with that.

Essentially, in my code behind, I have a separate class. I think this is being used for MVVM, though I have almost no idea what that kind of means (I get the point, but it looks confusing!).

Anyway... Here is my code in a seperate class (same namespace) to the code behind for my WPF form:

```
public class ChartViewModel
    {
        public ChartViewModel()
        {
            DataTable dataNames = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                var db = new SQLiteDatabase();
                string query = "SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Main";
                ...
```

Now, I have a textblock on my WPF xaml page, named AccountType. The text within this can cycle between three different values, and I need to change the string query at the end of that code block above based on that. If it is one value, the string = x. if its the second value, the string = y etc...

That part of the class is used to populate a combobox with entries from a database. Will changing that string then automatically force the combobox to update? Or will I ned to do something else after this also?

As requested, here is my XAML (the relevant stuff anyway)

```
<ComboBox x:Name="NameBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" Width="100" />
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <ProgressBar x:Name="AccountTypeProgress" Width="70" Height="20" MouseDown="AccountTypeButton_Click" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="AccountType" Text="Main" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF252525" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" MouseDown="AccountTypeButton_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Full ViewModel

```
public class ChartViewModel
{
    public ChartViewModel()
    {
        AccountType = "Main";

        DataTable dataNames = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            var db = new SQLiteDatabase();
            string query = "SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Main";

            dataNames = db.GetDataTable(query);
        }
        catch (Exception fail)
        {
            string error = "The following error has occured:\n\n";
            //error += fail.Message.ToString() + "\n\n";
            //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(error);
        }

        this.Names = new ObservableCollection<string> { };

        foreach (DataRow row in dataNames.Rows)
        {
            string name = row["Name"].ToString();
            Names.Add(name);
        }


        int x = 42067;

        DataTable datastats = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            var db = new SQLiteDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM Main WHERE Name = \"9n\"";
            datastats = db.GetDataTable(query);
        }
        catch (Exception fail)
        {
            String error = "The following error has occurred:\n\n";
            //error += fail.Message.ToString() + "\n\n";
            //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(error);
        }

        this.overall = new List<DataPoint>
        {
            //foreach(DataRow row in datastats.Rows)
            //{

            //}
        };

        foreach (DataRow row in datastats.Rows)
        {
            DateTime sDate = DateTime.Parse(row["Date"].ToString());
            //int date = ((sDate.Year - 1900)) + sDate.Day;
            sDate = sDate.Date;
            double date = sDate.ToOADate() - 1;
            int dateint = Convert.ToInt32(date);

            string sLevel = row["OverallL"].ToString();
            int level = Convert.ToInt32(sLevel);

            this.overall.Add(new DataPoint(date, level));

        }

        this.overall.Add(new DataPoint(42100, 10));
        this.overall.Add(new DataPoint(42110, 10));

        this.Title2 = "Example 2";
        this.Points = new List<DataPoint>
            {
                new DataPoint(x, 4),
                new DataPoint(42077, 13),
                new DataPoint(42087, 15),
                new DataPoint(42097, 16),
                new DataPoint(42107, 12),
                new DataPoint(42117, 12)
            };
        this.Data = new List<DataPoint>
            {
                new DataPoint(42067, 10),
                new DataPoint(42077, 15),
                new DataPoint(42087, 16),
                new DataPoint(42097, 20),
                new DataPoint(42107, 10),
                new DataPoint(42117, 12)
            };
    }


    public string Title2 { get; private set; }

    public IList<DataPoint> Points { get; private set; }
    public IList<DataPoint> Data { get; private set; }
    public IList<DataPoint> overall { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Names { get; private set; }

    private string _AccountType;

    public string AccountType
    {
        get { return _AccountType; }
        set
        {
            _AccountType = value;

            //OnPropertyChanged stuff here.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide some XAML? Are you binding the text to anything?

Comment: I have added the relevant XAML in OP. :) Clicking the progress base or text block is what makes the textblock value cycle between the three values, thats all the methods attached to those do.

Comment: Add the "Names" property code. If this is a simple list you need to convert this to observablecollection. The complete viewmodel code will be more helpful to answer

Comment: Added all viewmodel code now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, in your ViewModel, you can create a property for your AccountType textblock to bind to:

```
private string _AccountType;

    public string AccountType
    {
        get { return _AccountType; }
        set 
        { 
            _AccountType = value; 

            //OnPropertyChanged stuff here.
        }
    }
```

When you cycle the account types, update this property, it will also update the UI.

You first need to set the binding on your TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding AccountType}" ... />
```

Then you can simply use this property in your query.

*That part of the class is used to populate a combobox with entries from a database. Will changing that string then automatically force the combobox to update? Or will I ned to do something else after this also?*

It's good practice to use an ObservableCollection for lists that you are binding to from your UI. If you are not using this already, then please do so, as it handles the property changed stuff for you, and will update the bindings when an item is added/removed from the list.

Please let me know if I have missed anything.

Comment: Looks good, but one thing I still can't grasp - I want to cycle the values onclick of either progressbar or textblock... The onclick method is in my page's main namespace, but the viewmodel is a different namespace. I can't seem to reference anything between them... How would I go about doing so?

Comment: In this scenario, you should use an ICommand to cycle the the values. Your ICommand should be a property within your ViewModel, and your TextBlock can bind to it through InputBindings. It's a big topic to explain in a single comment, but here's a tutorial [on using ICommand](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/813345/Basic-MVVM-and-ICommand-usuage-example) and here's another on [input bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794918/wpf-how-to-use-command-input-bindings). Note, the second link doesn't go into full details, but what you're looking for is MouseBinding, not KeyBinding.

Comment: I still can't work this out even with all the helpful links. :( I have updated main post with my code for viewmodel... I have the combobox being populated with data from the Main database table (set using the SQL query). But, I need two things. I cant work out how to cycle the textbox onclick using the accountname string... Also, I then need to set the query string for the combobox filling from Names based on the value of the textblock. Thanks