# Beginner tutorial on MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have spent the past several hours finding tutorials on MVVM for WPF.

I am a good way into writing pretty much my first big WPF application, and being used to "the old way" of doing things, I was not using MVVM / didn't really know what it even was.

So, I have started using some library where I am basiclly required now to use MVVM... (As I found out here: [How do I check on the properties of WPF elements whilst in a different class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900356/how-do-i-check-on-the-properties-of-wpf-elements-whilst-in-a-different-class))

I have been trying to do my best with tutorials ETC, but I am lacking in my knowledge that I just lose every single tutorial nad have no idea what is going on.

I am someone who can do a lot with what I know, but see me as someone who knows about classes, knows they usually are seperated into different files, but ideally would prefer to just have one mega long class. Do you know of any material which can shift me away from defaulting to wanting to do thigns this way, and fully understanding what I'm doing with MVVM?

The more interactive the tutorial etc, the better... :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually would say that this is off-topic, but this question is being asked so often, that it probably deserves an answer.

I swear by this gentleman and everyone I've recommended him to has been satisfied:

**DCOM Engineering, LCC (YouTube)**: https://www.youtube.com/user/dcomnetwork

You will find two MVVM series.  The first is the [Introduction to Model-View-ViewModel Pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpGvqVtSYjs&list=PL356CA0B2C8E7548D) series and the other is the [Enterprise MVVM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lool8Ut58Xw&list=PLw8ap9mWnEiJOB8Ib6w93YXUCwiVIa42e) series.  he posted the second one very recently.  I would start with the first one to get a very clear understanding and move to the second one to solidify what you've learned.

He speaks clearly, in "plain-enough" language and does a very good job of covering topics without convolution involving finer details, in which most of the beginners get lost.

Comment: I was looking for this same question a few months ago when I started learning WPF. DCOM Engineering's videos are what I found and _really_ helped me a lot, would totally recommend them.

Comment: I'm curious why someone would downvote this answer without providing feedback.  Such is the way of trolls.

Comment: Have an extra upvote from me then :)