# WPF: simplest way to call some method by shortcut

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I checked a lot of of answers here about shortcuts bindings, but did not find the simple way to execute some **method** from the C# code.

First, in the following classic example I don't understand what actually we are binding. What the meaning of `Command` attribute? What is the `ApplicationCommands`? Where is `ApplicationCommands.Open` has been declared?

```
<Window.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"
              Gesture="CTRL+R" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

In the one of answer of question similar to my one, *"XAML is the markup language, so we could not call the method from there"* has been told. OK, in this case, WHY we can call the method `OnClickBtn1` from the code below?

```
<Button 
    x:Name="SomeButton"
    Click="OnClickBtn1"/>
```

Finally, my problem. All I need is to execute `OnClickBtn1` method by `Ctrl+H` (for example) shortcut same as effect when the button `Btn1` clicked. I understand that following code is not enough.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="MainDisplay" 
        <!-- ... --->
>

    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+H" Command="{Binding OnClickBtn1}" />
    </Window.InputBindings>

    <!-- ... -->

    <Button x:Name="Btn1"
    Width="70" 
    Content="Button" 
    Click="OnClickBtn1"/>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void OnClickBtn1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Btn1 has been clicked or Ctrl+H had been inputed");
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to call methods directly from xaml, you can try Caliburn.Micro Actions (https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions). But all you really need is a step by step tutorial on WPF, MVVM and commands.

Comment: answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20794919/492